# How to make the font size to be responsive to it's parent's div's height? Not the window resize action?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm a beginner developer and working on a simple word game. The play area size is fixed to the user device's screen size, and it is all defined at load. For the list of user input words I use grid and it fills the container with new rows as user adds more words to it. As the parent's container's height is fixed, when there's more words than the container can fit, for now I used `overflow : scroll;` but it would be better if all words were visible at all times.

```html
<div class="grid-cell user-word-list">
  <div class="user-word-container">
    <p class="user-word">seahorse</p>
  </div>
  <div class="user-word-container">
    <p class="user-word">slimfit</p>
  </div>
  <div class="user-word-container">
    <p class="user-word">dlowjod</p>
  </div>
  <div class="user-word-container">
    <p class="user-word">blowtorch</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

so I have successfully made the `.user-word-container` to fill the `.user-word-list` dynamically changing their heights with `grid-template-rows: (auto 1fr);` but I just can't make the text inside of them shrink accordingly. I suspect that it's possible through javascript but I don't have enough knowledge to execute it and googling didn't bring any results. Thanks and peace!

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the parent font size to 2vh then specifying a em size for the child. the em keeps it relative to its parents font size which is set based on its height.
Example:

```
<div style='font-size: 2vw;'>
  <div style='font-size: 4em;'>
    TEst
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: tried it, and it gave me the same result. If I understand it right with the value  of `2vw` the text will stay the same as long as the viewport width is unchanged, or am I wrong?

Comment: @veloped `em`s define a size that is relative to the font-size of the parent element. `1em` would be 100% of the size of the parent, `.5em` would be half the size of the parent, etc. If the parent's font-size changes, then the child's will too.

Comment: @ScottMarcus ugh I meant `vw`, just edited, sorry for waisting your time on this :/

Comment: ya you are right about the vw, i see i misunderstood

Comment: @ScottMarcus gonna duplicate it here, since it's relevant to this one too. See, the only thing that changes - is the height of these single word divs, so I need the font size inside of them to somehow listen to that height

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone who was here to help! I figured out my own original solution, here it is.

1.Getting the parent element:
`const userWords = document.querySelector('.user-word-list');`

2.bringing it to an array and iterating over it every time a new word gets added like so:

`Array.from(userWords.children).forEach(w => {`

`const boxHeight = w.offsetHeight;`

`const heightString = boxHeight.toString();`

``` w.style.fontSize = ``${heightString}``+'px';}); ```

the result - it listens to my shrinking divs heights and changes font accordingly. The only thing it kinda cascades them from bigger word to smaller one, until there's not enough space for that and then they are all at minimum height, but I kinda like how it looks. Please, let me know if you know why it happens!